# Roof Gutter Installation

Tags: gutters

I recently had rain gutters installed on my house. Should house gutters have gaps/spaces between the facia board and the gutters? My gutters appear to be leaking.

Comment: Pictures always help. It's not a bad idea to have a gap between the gutters and the facia board to allow for drying and airflow.  Unfortunately many times the roofing material doesn't extend far enough to allow for this.  Since you are new to SE,, please take the tour as well. You also need to be more specific about WHERE the gutters are leaking. Again, pics are a great help.

Comment: Even your location in the world can help get local advice.